How to set a window icon once in Tkinter for all dialogs including messagebox on Windows?
On Linux using Tkinter and TtkBootstrap, you can set up a logo once with:
logo = tb.PhotoImage(file="images/favicon.png")
root.iconphoto(True, logo)


This ensures that the logo is shown on every Toplevel and in messagebox.showerror/info/warning dialogs.
However, on Windows, you have to use .iconbitmap('images/favicon.ico') for each Toplevel. Unfortunately, the icon does not appear in messagebox.showerror/info/warning dialogs,and it only appears the Tkinter logo or the Ttkbootstrap logo.
Is there any function in Tkinter where you can define the logo once on Windows, and more importantly, ensure that the logo appears in messagebox.showerror/info/warning dialogs?
I tried to find something by asking ChatGPT, but it doesn't know and there aren't any questions about that on the internet.

Simply use root.iconbitmap(default = 'images/favicon.ico') to propagate icon to all Toplevel windows.

.iconphoto(True, logo) should also work on Windows.
Below is an example:
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox
import ttkbootstrap as tb

def show_dialog():
    messagebox.showinfo("Hello", "Hello World")

def show_window():
    win = tb.Toplevel()
    win.geometry("300x100")
    win.title("Secondary Window")

root = tk.Tk()
logo = tb.PhotoImage(file="lenna.png")
root.iconphoto(True, logo)

tk.Button(root, text="Window", command=show_window).pack(padx=100, pady=30)
tk.Button(root, text="Dialog", command=show_dialog).pack(padx=100, pady=30)

root.mainloop()

Result:




It worked, I used favicon.ico in the fuction PhotoImage but it seems that only works with PNG images

@JosephMoraila As said by Derek in the comment, you can use root.iconbitmap(default="images/favicon.ico").

It doesn't work using tb.Window()
